# Can I shrink the size of the Windows 7 start menu?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have removed a lot of things from the Windows 7 start menu that I don't use, and now I want to make the start menu smaller.  Refer to the image below to see what I mean.  There is a lot of empty space I'd like to be rid of.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At properties for taskbar, you can set numbers of items at start menu.

- Number of recent programs to display
- Number of recent items to display in Jump Lists

[image]