# windows 7 start menu doesn't get shorter when elements are removed?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I shrink the size of the Windows 7 start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/69564/can-i-shrink-the-size-of-the-windows-7-start-menu)

I have removed all elements from the start menu, but the menu doesn't get any shorter. Why is that, and how can I get it to shrink?

[image]

EDIT:

Ok, got it down to this size:

[image]

By checking "store and display recently opened programs in the start menu", then in the customize menu setting number of recent programs and items to 0. Quite an unintuitive way to do it, bad interface on microsofts part...

Comment: thanks. yes it was, didn't find it while searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/7945f282-6276-4329-8613-aa6a22586401) on this topic

But still I think it has something called **Minimum fixed height**

Comment: Thanks. i couldn't find any "Minimum fixed height" though.